# Add string to beginning of list items

Tags: python, string, list

I have generated a list of questions and stored these in a list.  I need to add a question number to the beginning of each item in the list.  Obviously I need to start at 1 to increment to the end of the list.

Item: 5 + 6? shoud become Q1: 5 + 6?

kind regards,
Matt

Comment: Why do you need to change the list items? Just print the index+1 when showing the questions in your loop.

Comment: You forgot to include the code you wrote that produces the incorrect output.

Comment: `for i,question in enumerate(list_): print('Q',i+1,question)`

Comment: `['Q'+str(i)+': '+value for i,value in enumerate(your_list,1)]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pythons [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and enumerate:

```py
original_list = ['question one?', 'question two?']
new_list = [f'Q{index}: {item}' for index, item in enumerate(original_list,1)]
```

This will lead to:

```
new_list
['Q1: question one?', 'Q2: question two?']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[ "Q"+str(n+1)+": "+v for n,v in enumerate(["a", "b"])]
Out[7]: ['Q1: a', 'Q2: b']
```

will do it.

Answer (score 0):

While the comprehension is a neat Python tool, if you prefer 
to change the list without creating a new one, you can simply loop over the original list and change each element one by one.
If list or strig are large use string interpolation `%`, it is usually faster than concatenation ( + ). I usually even use it for small tasks to form a habit.

```
questions = ["Item: 2 + 4", "Item: 2 - 4"]

for i, q in enumerate(questions):
    questions[i] = "Q%s%s" % (i + 1, q[4:])


print (questions)
```

Comment: huh why `i+1` when you can do `enumerate(questions,1)`

Comment: I guess I prefer explicit to implicit too much

Comment: I use interpolation over concatenation though, because even though sometimes less readable, in many real cases the speed up is substantial, while with enumerate, the speed-up is marginal.